# C# GUI application that stores an array and displays the highest and lowest numbers by clicking a button

Tags: c#

**Background:**
This is updated from 13 hours ago as I have been researching and experimenting with this for a few. I'm new to this programming arena so I'll be short, I'm teaching myself C#
 
And I'm trying to learn how to have integers from a user's input into a textbox get calculated from a button1_Click to appear on the form. Yes, this is a class assignment but I think I have a good handle on some of this but not all of it; that's why I'm turning to you guys.

**Problem:** 
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in C# language, Windows Forms Application and I need to create a GUI that allows a user to enter in 10 integer values that will be stored in an array called from a button_Click object. These values will display the highest and lowest values that the user inputted. The only thing is that the array must be declared above the Click() method.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
namespace SmallAndLargeGUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void inputText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = inputText.Text;
        }

        public void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int userValue; 
            if(int.TryParse(inputText.Text, out userValue)) 
        { 

        } 
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid integer into the text box.");
        } 


            int x;
            x = Convert.x.ToString();
            int squaredResults = squared(x);
            int cubedResults = cubed(x); squared(x);
            squaredLabel.Text = x.ToString() + " squared is " + squaredResults.ToString();
            cubedLabel.Text = x.ToString() + " cubed is " + cubedResults.ToString();
        }
        public static int squared(int x)
        {
            x = x * x;
            return x;
        }
        public static int cubed(int x)
        {
            x = x * squared(x);
            return x;    
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can't run this program because line 38 shows an error message of: 'System.Convert' does not contain a definition for 'x' Also I still have to have an array that holds 10 integers from a textbox and is declared above the Click() method. Please guys, any help for me? This was due yesterday.

Comment: There are two things you have to do.  For each number entered, convert it from a string to an int and store it at the first unused index in the array.  After ten numbers are entered, you have to loop through the array and set your min and max variables.  If you have a go at those two tasks and get back to us with any problems we can help.  People here probably don't want to do your homework for you.

Comment: You say you're having trouble getting the array values to appear. You haven't populated the array yet. What's not working, what specifically are you having trouble with, and what have you tried?

Comment: If you're having trouble putting code in a comment, you can edit it into the question at the bottom.

Comment: Am i even declaring the array and is it within the correct module so that the click button can return those values?

Comment: The array is declared within the class, but it isn't referenced at all in the Click handler method.  It also isn't being filled at all - you're just setting Form1.Text but never reading it back.  Is this for homework?  If it is, you'll need different advice than if it's a personal learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, so you should try a bit more than that. Here is what you could do: parse the string (say it's a comma-separated list of numbers), cast each value to `int` and populate your array. You can either call `.Max()` / `.Min()` methods or loop through the values of the array and get the max / min value. Here is a bit of code:

```
int n = 10;
int[] numbers = (from sn in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(inputText.Text, @"\s*,\s*") select int.Parse(sn)).ToArray();
int max = numbers.Max();
int min = numbers.Min();
//int max = numbers[0];
//int min = numbers[0];
//for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
//{
//    if(max < numbers[i])
//    {
//        max = numbers[i];
//    }
//    if(min > numbers[i])
//    {
//        min = numbers[i];
//    }
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

This in all probability being a homework I will not provide entire solution but just provide a hint.

Task to me seems to be to some how accept 10 integers and then show smallest and largest of them. For this there is no need to maintain an array (off-course only if maintaining an array is itself not part of the problem). You just need to keep track of current minimum and current maximum.

As and when you receive an input compare it with the current minimum and maximum and update them accordingly. e.g.

```
if(num < curr_min) curr_min = num;
```