# C# textbox user input processed by a button object

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# GUI application that stores an array and displays the highest and lowest numbers by clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237075/c-sharp-gui-application-that-stores-an-array-and-displays-the-highest-and-lowest)

This is updated from 13 hours ago as I have been researching and experimenting with this for a few. I'm new to this programming arena so I'll be short, I'm teaching myself C# and I'm trying to learn how to have integers from a user's input into a textbox get calculated from a button1_Click to appear on the form. Yes, this is a class assignment but I think I have a good handle on some of this but not all of it; that's why I'm turning to you guys. Thanks for all of the advice guys.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in C# language. I'm using Windows Forms Application and I need to create a GUI that allows a user to enter in 10 integer values that will be stored in an array called from a button_Click object. These values will display the highest and lowest values that the user inputted. The only thing is that the array must be declared above the Click() method.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
namespace SmallAndLargeGUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void inputText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = inputText.Text;
        }

        public void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int userValue; 
            if(int.TryParse(inputText.Text, out userValue)) 
        { 

        } 
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid integer into the text box.");
        } 


            int x;
            x = Convert.x.ToString();
            int squaredResults = squared(x);
            int cubedResults = cubed(x); squared(x);
            squaredLabel.Text = x.ToString() + " squared is " + squaredResults.ToString();
            cubedLabel.Text = x.ToString() + " cubed is " + cubedResults.ToString();
        }
        public static int squared(int x)
        {
            x = x * x;
            return x;
        }
        public static int cubed(int x)
        {
            x = x * squared(x);
            return x;    
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can't run this program because line 38 shows an error message of: 'System.Convert' does not contain a definition for 'x' Also I still have to have an array that holds 10 integers from a textbox and is declared above the Click() method. Please guys, any help for me? This was due yesterday.

Comment: show us what you are trying and we'll help guide you in the right direction :)

Comment: what type of C# application is this webforms, winforms, wpf, etc?

Comment: Downvoted...He asked the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237075/c-sharp-gui-application-that-stores-an-array-and-displays-the-highest-and-lowest. Instead of editing the original question to clarify it, he has created a new question.

Answer (score 3):

As a couple of comments have mentioned, there really isn't enough information here to provide you with a useful answer. There are two main User Interface frameworks in .Net for windows applications. One of these is commonly referred to as "WinForms" and the other is "WPF" or "Windows Presentation Foundation."

I'm going to go with you are most likely using WinForms as it is the older of the two technologies. The approach here can be used on both sides with a little tweaking. Setting text in a text box is very similar to setting text programaticly on a label. You can get more detail on that on MSDN: [How to: Display Text on a Windows Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383971%28v=vs.90%29); [How to: Use TextBox Controls to Get User Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397491%28v=vs.90%29).

If you are using WPF the "back end" code is pretty much the same. You just need to make sure your textbox has an `x:Name="userInputTextBox"` so you can reference it in your code behind. **Be mindful** that your users can input "1", "3" or "abcd" in the field. Ensuring your app doesn't bomb is most likely outside of the assignment but feel free to look up C# `int.TryParse(...)` and "Try Catch" :-)

Your button handler could look like this:

```
void btnUserClick_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int userValue;
    if(int.TryParse(txtUserInput.Text, out userValue))
    {
        // We have the value successfully, do calculation
    }
    else
    {
        // We don't have the users value.
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid integer into the text box.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. define the textbox named textbox1 or txt_name
2. you can write the button1_Click function :

   ```
   int i_value = Convert.ToInt16(txt_name.Text);
   ```

ok. I haven't try catch the exceptions.... :(

maybe above answer is right.

btw, i think this question mainly focus on how to get int type from text box. right?

Comment: What if the value is invalid? Use `System.Short.TryParse(string, out short)`

Comment: or wrap it in a try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

In your `retrieveInput_Click` handler you are assigning the min/max numbers to a local int.  Once you determine your min/max numbers in the logic, you will need to assign those local integers to a UI element for display.

Since we don't have any details on your specific UI choices, one simple solution could be to add 2 labels to your form, and then in the code you would place the result in the label:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
{
  if (numbers[i] < min)
     min = numbers[i];
  if (numbers[i] > max)
     max = numbers[i];
}

// Assign Minimum to Label1
Label1.Text = "Minimum Value: " + min.ToString();
// Assign Maximum to Label2
Label2.Text = "Maximum Value: " + max.ToString();
```